What can I do about model tuning parameter instability?
I am trying to determine the importance of watershed characteristics on the slope of the concentration-discharge relationship for several rivers. I am using partial least squares regression (plsr) because of multicollinearity between the watershed characteristics. After fitting the plsr model, I was going to use variable importance on projection to rank the watershed characteristics in explaining the response variables.
My first step is to determine the ideal number of components for plsr using caret::train. However, the number of components varies drastically depending on the seed and cross validation method. Here is a link to my data and my code is below. Note that column 1 term is the response variable and the remaining columns are the predictors.
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

# load data

load('Processed_Data/df1.Rdata')

# set up different CV methods:

trC.cv <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
trC.repeatedcv <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)
trC.LGOCV <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = 0.8)
trC.boot <- trainControl(method = "boot")
trC.LOOCV <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")

# combine CV methods into list:

l.trCon <- list(trC.boot, trC.cv, trC.repeatedcv, trC.LGOCV, trC.LOOCV)
names(l.trCon) <- c("trC.boot", "trC.cv", "trC.repeatedcv", "trC.LGOCV", "trC.LOOCV")

# function to compare ncomp across different seeds/cv methods:

fun.compare.plsr.models <- function(df, seeds){
  df.i <- data.frame(seed = NA, CV.method = NA, ncomp = NA) # initialize df to cbind to for each i loop:
  for (i in seq_along(seeds)){ # loop through the seeds:
    v.CV.method <- NA # initialize vectors for Cv method and ncomp for each j loop:
    v.ncomp <- NA
    for(j in seq_along(l.trCon)){ # loop through CV methods:
      set.seed(i) # set seed:
      model.j <- train(term ~., data = df, # build model using CV method corresponding to j loop:
                       method = 'pls', 
                       scale = TRUE, 
                       trControl = l.trCon[[j]], 
                       tuneGrid = data.frame(ncomp = c(1:30)))
      v.CV.method[j] <- names(l.trCon)[j] # set vector element for j loop:
      v.ncomp[j] <- model.j$bestTune[1,1]
    }
    df.j <- data.frame(seed = i, CV.method = v.CV.method, ncomp = v.ncomp) # create df with resulting vectors from j loop:
    df.i <- rbind(df.i, df.j) # cbind j loop df to overall df:
  }
  df.i <- df.i[-1,] # remove first row since it was NA:
  return(df.i)
}

# run function (takes a minute to run):

system.time(df.compare10 <- fun.compare.plsr.models(df = df1, seeds = 1:10)) # 95 seconds

# look at results:

ggplot(df.compare10, aes(x = seed, y = ncomp, color = CV.method)) +
  geom_line()

Other than this post, I have not been able to find online resources related to 'instability in model tuning parameters' (also in that post they did not provide an example of instability, which I believe I am seeing here).
What does it mean that I am seeing parameter instability? Is there anything I can do to fix it?
I have looked at PCA to identify outlier observations, but I am hesitant to throw away data.
My only other thought is that the relationship between the response variable and the predictors does not exist in the framework of a plsr model. Maybe I should try another model? I am new to caret and cross validation so please forgive the multiple questions/vagueness of this post. I have really tried to scour the web for help on this but I have not found any examples similar to mine.
Any help is much appreciated.

Do I understand correctly that the "instability" is that you find different ranking of "watershed characteristics in explaining the response variables" depending on your choice of tuning parameters?

When I say instability I mean the different values for the number of components (i.e. the tuning parameter) chosen by train .  I have not looked at the rankings yet.

I don't know your data, but for some data the model is just not well identified, i.e., quite different looking models have very similar quality, and the data have a hard time to distinguish between them. In such a situation you can easily observe instability trying out different tuning. If your cross-validation indicates that all these models have rather similar quality, this indicates that that could be the issue. (This isn't necessarily an indication aginst this approach, it may also happen with others.)

I'd support to not throw away data (unless you can nail down that something went wrong with some data for other reasons than looking outlying alone), but you may be better off with something robust if you have outliers. You could google for robust PLS.

Even under ideal circumstances, you shouldn't expect different resampling methods to behave the same way. For example, this web page compares different types of cross validation (CV) in the ability to choose tuning parameters for random-forest fits to known, simulated linear regression data. The methods have different tradeoffs between bias and variance and perform differently in choosing tuning parameters and subsequent model quality. The author of the page doesn't even consider leave-one-out CV, with its low bias but high variance.
Any remaining "instability" (e.g., within each type of resampling, depending on the seed) probably comes from the same multicollinearity that led you to consider partial least squares (PLS) regression in the first place. I suspect that corresponding high variance in PLS is leading to the difficulty in deciding how many components to keep.
Unlike principal components regression (PCR), in which highly correlated predictors will tend to be included in the same component, PLS does not directly take the correlations among predictors into account. As explained in Section 6.3.2 of An Introduction to Statistical Learning, PLS starts with a first component based on individual correlations of predictors with outcome, constructs the second component based on "the remaining information that has not been explained by the first PLS direction," and continues similarly for subsequent components.
Quoting more extensively from that Section:

In practice [PLS] often performs no better than ridge regression or PCR. While the supervised dimension reduction of PLS can reduce bias, it also has the potential to increase variance, so that the overall benefit of PLS relative to PCR is a wash.

The multicollinearity is going to pose a problem with your ultimate goal "to rank the watershed characteristics in explaining the response variables," anyway. When predictors are correlated, their relative rank orders can depend heavily on the vagaries of the data sample, depending on which of the correlated predictors happened to work "better" in that sample.
How to proceed depends to some extent on the scale of your data set. If you have enough data to fit all of your predictors in a standard model without overfitting, you could consider the measures of relative explained variation described in Section 5.1.3 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies (RMS). As shown there, you can check the stability of the importance rankings by repeating the modeling on multiple bootstrap samples of your data.
Alternatively, you could take advantage of the collinearity to perform data reduction, removing or combining predictors in a way that doesn't take the outcome values into account and thus doesn't prevent reliable inference. Chapter 8 of RMS has an extensively worked-through example. Or consider a penalized method, like ridge regression (which can be considered an extension of PCR, with components weighted differentially instead of selected all-or-none) or LASSO (with its built-in predictor selection).
If you want to stick with PLS, I suspect that repeated 10-fold CV will be a good choice for choosing the tuning parameter (number of components to keep). To document whether your ultimate variable-importance rankings are stable, repeat the entire modeling process (including tuning-parameter choice) on multiple bootstrapped samples of your data.
